# Lubuntu: autorun after GUI loads, either a script, or a desktop app (with a script)

Tags: scripts, lubuntu

I am trying to have Lubuntu run a script as soon as the desktop as loaded after logging in. Right now there is a desktop application for a user to double click that runs the script. I would rather have it auto start when the desktop is finished loading. Any ideas?

Every solution I have tried loads the application before the desktop environment is completed and it doesn't work properly without user interaction.

Also: I am limited to the terminal to make this work. I cannot use the interface in the desktop environment.